# How not show "Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started" in file log4j

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I want to avoid `Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started` message in File for Log4J.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share your configuration file (`log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`)? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j.xml configuration file set something like this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="file.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="trace"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d (%5.5t)[%c{1}] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework.web.context">
    <level value="warn"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```